# How to put paragraph center right below navbar

Tags: html, css

I have created a `navbar` at the top of my page and I want to center some paragraphs right below it. The paragraphs are centered but are down below the page. How do I get them back up to a view visible wihout scrolling down. Essentially, the `row`and `col` div

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <h1>Sparison</h1>
  <P>Music Matching With Love ❤️ </P>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS i tried is;

```
.col{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
min-height: 0vh;
}

*{
 margin : 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }

.container{
width: 100%; 
height: 100vh;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
padding-left: 8%;
padding-right: 8%;
box-sizing: border-box ;
}

.navbar{
height: 12%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

nav{
flex: 1;
text-align: right;
}


nav ul li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 60px;
}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `height: 100vh;` on the `.container`, thats why the content is forced down. Use something like `height: 20vh;` on the container like so:

```css
.col{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
min-height: 0vh;
}

*{
 margin : 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }

.container{
width: 100%; 
height: 20vh;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
padding-left: 8%;
padding-right: 8%;
box-sizing: border-box ;
}

.navbar{
height: 12%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

nav{
flex: 1;
text-align: right;
}


nav ul li{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 60px;
}

nav ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <h1>Sparison</h1>
  <P>Music Matching With Love ❤️ </P>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Np, if you encounter something familiar, try opening your page on the browsers inspector, and just start at the top, work your way down. The `container` was so large, that it force everything down. With the help of the inspector, it's quite easy to spot something like this

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap for align the praghraph to right you can add justify-content-end to the row

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
         <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
           <nav>
            <ul>
       <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-end">
       <div class="col">
      <h1>Sparison</h1>
   <P>Music Matching With Love ❤️ </P>
       </div>
      </div>
```

and if tou don't use bootstrap add row this css =>

```
.row{
   display:flex;
justify-content:flex-end;
   width:100%;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this puts the text at the bottom left corner of my screen, unfortunately

Comment: and also you'r container scrolling because your add to you'r container height:100vh; if you remove height:100vh you'r container does not scrolling

Answer (score -1):

Just use `text-align: center;`. Unless there is another reason why you wanted to use a flexbox.

```css
.col {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h1>Sparison</h1>
    <P>Music Matching With Love ❤️ </P>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I just did. I want the text right below the `navbar`